# PHP/Codeigniter cannot redeclare class - require_once and class_exists have failed me

Tags: php, codeigniter, declaration

I've run into a bewildering problem in our CodeIgniter-powered website. One PHP class - TChild - will intermittently start throwing "cannot redeclare class" errors and breaking every page that uses it. The lengths I've gone to to ensure that the declaring code runs only once have gotten frankly ridiculous, but to no avail. The top of tchild.php currently looks like this:

```
(!( isset( $GLOBALS['tchild_counter'] ) ))
    ? $GLOBALS['tchild_counter'] = 1 
    : $GLOBALS['tchild_counter']++ ;
log_message("info", "tchild has been included " . $GLOBALS['tchild_counter'] . " times");

if($GLOBALS['tchild_counter'] != 1) {
    log_message("info", "STOP RUNNING TWICE");
} else {

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) {
    log_message("error", "BASEPATH not set; no direct script access allowed");
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
}
log_message("info", "Basepath is fine, checking if tchild exists (proc".getmypid().")");
log_message("info", "why does that last line seem to run twice?");
if ( ! class_exists('TChild')) {
log_message("info", "TChild does not exist, creating it");
if(class_exists('tchild')) {
    log_message("info", "tchild apparently exists?");
} else {
    log_message("info","okay, I'm extra-sure that tchild doesn't exist");
}

class TChild extends ActiveRecord\Model {
```

It's a gigantic pile of... *something*, but at least it should ensure that TChild is only defined once, right? Well, no. Mostly, it works fine, but occasionally the server will get into some strange state where it decides, despite all evidence to the contrary, that TChild is being declared twice. From the extensive logging statements I've added, I'm fairly certain that tchild.php is only included by a single require_once to begin with, and it definitely doesn't get to the class definition more than once. (It does, however, spit out two "STOP RUNNING TWICE" log entries, even when things are running fine. I don't know why, but at least that doesn't break anything.)

Once it starts failing, it will continue to break everything for (usually) a few minutes, then fix itself for reasons as mysterious as the initial failure.

I have no idea what's going on here. Googling around led me to try adding apc.enabled = 0 to my php.ini, but it hasn't made a difference in the crash or in performance. (I don't think it was enabled to begin with, but it was worth a shot.)

**Update:**

Aha, there was a require statement in a third-party library that was including the file more than once. I still don't know why the class was being redeclared despite all the if/else blocks I had the declaration wrapped inside, but at least things seem to be working now.

Comment: What do your `include`s and `require`s look like? It might not be this file. Check to see if you missed using a `require_once` that references this file somewhere.

Comment: short open php tags enabled on server or being set somewhere else that isn't always called?  did you accidentally overwrite another file with this code so its inadvertantly redeclaring it?  I did something like that a month ago and got really frustrated thinking it was something super complicated but it was just me being dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than just echoing the fact that the file is included more than once, get PHP to tell you where it's coming from:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php
- inspired by John B's comment above, `__FILE__` might reveal that your file somehow has two names

Answer (score 0):

How about just returning after log_message("info", "STOP RUNNING TWICE"); return; or exit(0); seems your file is included more than once and you never stop in any part of your code. It just gets to the part where the `class TChild extends ActiveRecord\Model` and gets declared again.

If i where you just do:

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) {
    log_message("error", "BASEPATH not set; no direct script access allowed");
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
}

if (class_exists('TChild') || class_exists('tchild')) {
    log_message("info", "class already exists returning");
    return; // or exit(0);
}

class TChild extends ActiveRecord\Model {
…
```

You ask me you should check where the file is included from unless its included from some other pile of code, which is difficult to track down. But the code above should suffice.
You can use `debug_backtrace` to check out where your file is included from other utilities can be [xhprof](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof) or [xdebug](http://xdebug.org).